# How to splice item from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, javascript-objects

I am looking a way to delete all elements from array if target object attribute is present in array.

```
var msg={name:'tar', type:'SR'}; //want to delete all object with type=SR

  var items= [{name:'oh', type:'SR'},{name:'em', type:'PR'},
  {name:'ge', type:'MR'},{name:'ohoo', type:'SR'}];

    items.splice( items.indexOf(msg.type), 1 );
```

In this way only one object is deleting. Can someone suggest a better way that without using a loop i can delete all the target object from array

Comment: Are you trying to remove all elements from the array if at least one object contains a specific property with a specific value or are you trying to remove only the objects that have a specific property with a specific value?

Comment: Your code is deleting all objects except the last one, `items.indexOf(msg.type)` return `-1` as `indexOf` look for the value `"SR"`

Comment: I am trying to delete all those objects which have type:'SR'.

Comment: Then you should clarify the first sentence in your question.

Comment: Sorry I already mentioned this in a code comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like following

```
items = items.filter(function(item){
     return item.type !== msg.type;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

a bit of functional and it's done:

```
var result = items.filter(function(item){
    return (item.type == msg.type) ? false : true;
});
```